Model objective contains non-linear terms (pyomo)
I am trying to create a model to minimize the LCOH of an electrolyser. There are hourly values for the price and it should be decided on the basis of the quantity produced whether it is worthwhile to produce. All other values are initially constant. The idea is that the investment costs and variable costs are divided over the total quantity produced and the LCOH thus decreases up to a certain marginal price.
The LCOH is calculated from the investment costs plus the variable costs divided by the quantity produced. The investment costs are fixed at the beginning, the rest is determined by the hour of production.
If I try to include the fixed costs in the numerator and represent the variable costs using a sum with decision variables, I get the error that my function is not linear. I tried two different ways to define my objective function but both doesn't work. Can someone help me to solve this problem?
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.environ import *

# prices with values in €/MWh
el_prices =[-5.17, -1.07, -1.47, -5.08, -4.49, -5.4, -5.02, -1.3, -1.44, -1.09, -1.07, -1.07, -0.79, -0.27, 0.85, 23.53, 36.54, 46.03, 55.57, 54.95, 49.23, 44.99, 45.96, 35.0, 57.91, 51.67, 52.93, 44.09, 50.08, 69.72, 105.08, 140.64, 145.98, 147.05, 145.61, 143.35, 144.38, 143.76, 148.2, 155.34, 162.89, 170.0, 174.74, 164.46, 153.0, 141.67, 134.91, 124.22, 130.01, 120.0]
    
investment_cost_ely = 1500  # Beispiel-Fixkosten in Euro/kw
power_ely = 1000  # Beispiel-Leistung des Elektrolyseurs in kW
conversion_factor = 0.6  # Beispiel-Wirkungsgrad des Elektrolyseurs
number_years = 20
interest_rate = 0.06


a = (((1+interest_rate)**number_years)*interest_rate)/(((1+interest_rate)**number_years)-1)
annualized_cost = investment_cost_ely * power_ely * a


  
m3 = ConcreteModel()

    
m3.betriebsstunden = Var(hours, domain=Binary)

   
def gestehungskosten_rule(model):
    return fixe_kosten + sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * power_ely * el_prices[t]) / sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * power_ely * conversion_factor for t in hours)    
m3.gestehungskosten = Objective(rule=gestehungskosten_rule, sense=minimize)

Here I get this error
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Objective gestehungskosten
with index None: NameError: name 't' is not defined
ERROR: Constructing component 'gestehungskosten' from data=None failed:
        NameError: name 't' is not defined
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 10
      8 def gestehungskosten_rule(model):
      9     return fixe_kosten + sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * leistung * strompreise[t]) / sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * leistung * wirkungsgrad for t in hours)    
---> 10 m3.gestehungskosten = Objective(rule=gestehungskosten_rule, sense=minimize)
     12 m3.gestehungskosten.pprint()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py:568, in _BlockData.__setattr__(self, name, val)
    563 if name not in self.__dict__:
    564     if isinstance(val, Component):
    565         #
    566         # Pyomo components are added with the add_component method.
    567         #
--> 568         self.add_component(name, val)
    569     else:
    570         #
    571         # Other Python objects are added with the standard __setattr__
    572         # method.
    573         #
    574         super(_BlockData, self).__setattr__(name, val)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py:1126, in _BlockData.add_component(self, name, val)
   1118     logger.debug(
   1119         "Constructing %s '%s' on %s from data=%s",
   1120         val.__class__.__name__,
   (...)
   1123         str(data),
   1124     )
   1125 try:
-> 1126     val.construct(data)
   1127 except:
   1128     err = sys.exc_info()[1]

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/objective.py:318, in Objective.construct(self, data)
    315 else:
    316     # Bypass the index validation and create the member directly
    317     for index in self.index_set():
--> 318         ans = self._setitem_when_not_present(index, rule(block, index))
    319         if ans is not None:
    320             ans.set_sense(self._init_sense(block, index))

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/initializer.py:438, in ScalarCallInitializer.__call__(self, parent, idx)
    437 def __call__(self, parent, idx):
--> 438     return self._fcn(parent)

Cell In[7], line 9, in gestehungskosten_rule(model)
      8 def gestehungskosten_rule(model):
----> 9     return fixe_kosten + sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * leistung * strompreise[t]) / sum(m3.betriebsstunden[t] * leistung * wirkungsgrad for t in hours)

NameError: name 't' is not defined

This is my second approach
#define promo model second ry
m6 = ConcreteModel()

    # variables
fix_costs = 100000
m6.betriebsstunden = Var(hours, domain=Binary)

def gestehungskosten_rule(model):
    variable_costs = sum(m6.betriebsstunden[t] * power_ely * el_prices[t] for t in hours)
    quantity = sum(m6.betriebsstunden[t] * power_ely * conversion_factor for t in hours)
    return (fix_costs + variable_costs) / quantity
m6.gestehungskosten = Objective(rule=gestehungskosten_rule, sense=minimize)


    # solve problem
solver = SolverFactory('glpk')  # Anpassen des Solvers je nach Bedarf (glpk)
results = solver.solve(m6)

    # print result
print("Minimale Gestehungskosten:", m6.gestehungskosten())
print("Anzahl der Betriebsstunden:", sum(m6.betriebsstunden[t].value for t in hours))

print("Stunden mit Produktion:")
for t in hours:
    if m6.betriebsstunden[t].value == 1:
        print("Stunde:", t, "Strompreis:", el_prices[t])

Here this error comes up
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 # Solver konfigurieren und Problem lösen
      2 solver = SolverFactory('glpk')  # Anpassen des Solvers je nach Bedarf (glpk)
----> 3 results = solver.solve(m6)
      5 # Ergebnisse ausgeben
      6 print("Minimale Gestehungskosten:", m6.gestehungskosten())

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py:598, in OptSolver.solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    594 try:
    595     # we're good to go.
    596     initial_time = time.time()
--> 598     self._presolve(*args, **kwds)
    600     presolve_completion_time = time.time()
    601     if self._report_timing:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/opt/solver/shellcmd.py:222, in SystemCallSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    219 self._keepfiles = kwds.pop("keepfiles", False)
    220 self._define_signal_handlers = kwds.pop('use_signal_handling', None)
--> 222 OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    224 #
    225 # Verify that the input problems exists
    226 #
    227 for filename in self._problem_files:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py:704, in OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
    701 if self._problem_format:
    702     write_start_time = time.time()
    703     (self._problem_files, self._problem_format, self._smap_id) = (
--> 704         self._convert_problem(
    705             args, self._problem_format, self._valid_problem_formats, **kwds
    706         )
    707     )
    708     total_time = time.time() - write_start_time
    709     if self._report_timing:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py:756, in OptSolver._convert_problem(self, args, problem_format, valid_problem_formats, **kwds)
    755 def _convert_problem(self, args, problem_format, valid_problem_formats, **kwds):
--> 756     return convert_problem(
    757         args, problem_format, valid_problem_formats, self.has_capability, **kwds
    758     )

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/convert.py:97, in convert_problem(args, target_problem_type, valid_problem_types, has_capability, **kwds)
     95                 tmpkw = kwds
     96                 tmpkw['capabilities'] = has_capability
---> 97                 problem_files, symbol_map = converter.apply(*tmp, **tmpkw)
     98                 return problem_files, ptype, symbol_map
    100 msg = 'No conversion possible.  Source problem type: %s.  Valid target types: %s'

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/solvers/plugins/converter/model.py:78, in PyomoMIPConverter.apply(self, *args, **kwds)
     70         symbol_map_id = instance.write(
     71             problem_filename,
     72             format=ProblemFormat.cpxlp,
   (...)
     75             **io_options
     76         )
     77     else:
---> 78         (problem_filename, symbol_map_id) = instance.write(
     79             filename=problem_filename,
     80             format=ProblemFormat.cpxlp,
     81             solver_capability=capabilities,
     82             io_options=io_options,
     83         )
     84     return (problem_filename,), symbol_map_id
     85 else:
     86     #
     87     # I'm simply exposing a fatal issue with
   (...)
     90     # arguments that can be sent to the writer?
     91     #

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py:1937, in _BlockData.write(self, filename, format, solver_capability, io_options, int_marker)
   1934     def solver_capability(x):
   1935         return True
-> 1937 (filename, smap) = problem_writer(self, filename, solver_capability, io_options)
   1938 smap_id = id(smap)
   1939 if not hasattr(self, 'solutions'):
   1940     # This is a bit of a hack.  The write() method was moved
   1941     # here from PyomoModel to support the solution of arbitrary
   (...)
   1946     # dependency (we only need it here because we store the
   1947     # SymbolMap returned by the writer in the solutions).

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/repn/plugins/lp_writer.py:208, in LPWriter.__call__(self, model, filename, solver_capability, io_options)
    205     io_options['allow_quadratic_constraint'] = qc
    207 with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as FILE:
--> 208     info = self.write(model, FILE, **io_options)
    209 return filename, info.symbol_map

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/repn/plugins/lp_writer.py:241, in LPWriter.write(self, model, ostream, **options)
    237 # Pause the GC, as the walker that generates the compiled LP
    238 # representation generates (and disposes of) a large number of
    239 # small objects.
    240 with PauseGC():
--> 241     return _LPWriter_impl(ostream, config).write(model)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyomo/repn/plugins/lp_writer.py:378, in _LPWriter_impl.write(self, model)
    376 repn = objective_visitor.walk_expression(obj.expr)
    377 if repn.nonlinear is not None:
--> 378     raise ValueError(
    379         f"Model objective ({obj.name}) contains nonlinear terms that "
    380         "cannot be written to LP format"
    381     )
    382 if repn.constant or not (repn.linear or getattr(repn, 'quadratic', None)):
    383     # Older versions of CPLEX (including 12.6) and all versions
    384     # of GLPK (through 5.0) do not support constants in the
   (...)
    390     # objective, this will ensure we at least write out
    391     # 0*ONE_VAR_CONSTANT.
    392     repn.linear[id(ONE_VAR_CONSTANT)] = repn.constant

ValueError: Model objective (gestehungskosten) contains nonlinear terms that cannot be written to LP format

Thanks for any help

How many decision variables do you have ?

Actually, I only have one. The operating variable as a binary variable that decides whether production takes place at the hour in question or not. But since I want to look at a whole year and the variable for an hour is in the denominator and numerator, it ends up being 17520. In the current test code, I start with 50.

what you can try if you face non linear constraints is to use another python package : docplex and that API allows non linear constraints and objective since this relies on constraint programming
Small example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoononlinear.py
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus30')
mdl.add(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300)

#non linear objective
mdl.minimize(mdl.exponent(nbbus40)*500 + mdl.exponent(nbbus30)*400)

msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats") 

